# Getting changes from datagrid when button is clicked and updating a table in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I have an Access database with following 2 tables:

**LineItems**

[image: lineitems table]

**ItemDesc**

[image: ItemDesc table]

My issue is that after I query the ItemDesc table into a WPF Datagrid by way of dataTable so it can be edited I need to update the lineitems table if the ItemCode was changed.

For example if they change the ItemCode A to AA in the ItemDesc table after it has been put in the Datagrid, I need any A in the lineitems table to be changed to AA.

As of right now I am not querying the lineitems table at all. Do I need to put that in a datatable?

```
public DataTable GetDef()
{
    try
    {
        string sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [ItemDesc]";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sSQL, con);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name + "." + MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " -> " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This is how I'm getting the data into the dataTable and then into a dataGrid.

Comment: Would suggest you to map the data table with a ViewModel which will bind with View. ViewModel should implement INofityPropertyChanged. Once you create the ViewModel, maintain a flag which indicates if any column value has changed. If yes, save those to DB based on button click command.